# How to turn UNIX mode on in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when starting up Android Studio. (Version - 2.3.3 running on mas osx Yosemite)

```
  Error:Could not set UNIX mode on /Users/*nameHere*/.gradle/daemon/3.3: could not chmod file (errno 1: Operation not permitted)
  ----------------------------------------------------
  Gradle sync failed: Could not set UNIX mode on /Users/*nameHere*/.gradle/daemon/3.3: could not chmod file (errno 1: Operation not permitted)
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened after I restored project files from an old drive. It turns out for some reason, the directory owner had changed. A `chown` helped.

`sudo chown -R username /path/to/problematic/folder`

Answer (score 2):

I solved with a **build** > **clean project** in Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens to me when transferring files over to a new Git repository. We're going to make a couple of changes to your file structure, so before continuing be sure to make a back up of your project that you can always come back to.

Firstly, navigate to the root directory of your project and enable public file permissions:

```
chmod 777 -R *
```

Try to clean the Android Studio project. (**Build** > **Clean Project**)

The build may now fail because of contained executables. Ensure you provide these specific files with an executable permission:

```
chmod go+rx your/file/path
```

Finally, delete your project's `.gradle` files; you allow these to be re-initialized by calling **Clean Project** one last time.

Comment: Isn't 777 kind of overkill?  744?  764?  Is there really any reason to set all those file executable?

Comment: Yes, DO NOT just set all files to executable by anyone (`chmod 777 -R *` or `chmod go+rx` ). That is a terrible security risk. You have no idea what kind of executable might be buried in the project that you've just given any user permission to execute. This is a terrible action to take.

Comment: Updated the post with more secure defaults.. in case someone copy & pastes without reading comments...